# No subscriptions were found for 'None'. If this is expected, use '--allow-no-subscriptions' to have tenant level access

Tags: azure, powershell

I want to login to azure to run these commands on a web app:-

```
 az login
 az account set --subscription "Pay-As-You-Go"
 az webapp identity assign --name "****" --resource-group "****"
 az keyvault set-policy --name "****" --object-id "***" --secret-permissions get list
```

where we are managing our customers' azure through the Microsoft Partner Centre, as follow:-

[image]

when I click on a Customer >> then click on "view all resources on Azure portal" :-

[image]

then when I click on "View My Access" i will get this :-

[image]

But when I try to login to azure using PowerShell `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9>az login` using the same username i login to the UI, I will get this error:-

> You have logged in. Now let us find all the subscriptions to which you
> have access...  No subscriptions were found for 'None'. If this is
> expected, use '--allow-no-subscriptions' to have tenant level access

so I am confused because using the UI I can access the customer + create web apps for the customer.. so why when I login to azure using PowerShell I got the above error that i do not have subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the customer does not have licensed subscriptions, mentioned in the snippets you shared:

[image]

Try using below command instead:

```
az login --allow-no-subscriptions
```

Alternatively, if you have `Tenand Id` handy, you can use below command:

```
az login --tenant TENANT_ID
```